# Marshmallow Validation Error of Unknown field for Dict and List of Dict in POST payload

Tags: python, flask, marshmallow

This is a POST payload body received in backend for store and order generated in a test frontend application that includes 2 keys with objects List and a Object

```
{
    "orderedItems": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Asado",
        "amount": 2,
        "price": 15.99
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Sushi",
        "amount": 1,
        "price": 22.99
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Green Bowl",
        "amount": 1,
        "price": 18.99
    }
],
  "user": {
        "city": "Guatemala",
        "email": "dher@example.com",
        "name": "danny"
    }
}
```

Once is received I tried to validate in Marshmallow with `OrderSchema` nested Schema

```
from marshmallow import validate, validates, validates_schema, \
    ValidationError, post_dump, validates
from api import ma


class MealsOrderSchema(ma.Schema):
  id= ma.Integer(required=True)
  amount= ma.Integer(required=True)
  price= ma.Float()
  name= ma.String()


class UserDataSchema(ma.Schema):
  name= ma.String(required=True)
  email= ma.String(required=True, validate=[validate.Email()])
  city= ma.String()


class OrderSchema(ma.Schema):
  orderedItems= ma.Nested(MealsOrderSchema(many=True))
  userData= ma.Nested(UserDataSchema)
```

Validation is not pass for Object List or object neither, I checked in similar question or other blogs for workaround

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "description": "The server found one or more errors in the information that you sent.",
    "errors": {
        "json": {
            "orderedItems": [
                "Unknown field."
            ],
            "user": [
                "Unknown field."
            ]
        }
    },
    "message": "Validation Error"
}
```

Appreciate your hints, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to manage a list of objects you must use the `List` class.
While if the json field name is different from the property name in python, you have to specify which field to load via the `attribute` parameter

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class OrderSchema(Schema):
  orderedItems: fields.List(fields.Nested(MealsOrderSchema))
  userData: fields.Nested(UserDataSchema, attribute='user')
```